# Pointer in Java C/C++ conversion

Tags: java, c++, pointers

I'm trying to convert library from C++ to Java. I have a problem with pointer..

The code from C++ is:

```
int DECL2 daveSetBit(daveConnection * dc,int area, int DB, int byteAdr, int bitAdr) {
    int a=1;
    return daveWriteBits(dc, area, DB, 8*byteAdr+bitAdr, 1, &a);
}
```

and daveWriteBits declaration is:

```
 daveWriteBits(daveConnection * dc,int area, int DB, int start, int len, void * buffer)
```

How can I convert this into java? I don't know how to convert pointer **&a** into java language..

```
public int SetBits(
        int area,
        int DBnum,
        int byteAdr,
        int bitAdr) {       
    int a=1;        
    return writeBits(area, DBnum, 8*byteAdr+bitAdr, 1, ??? )            
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to add part of WriteBits function in Java..

```
public int writeBits(
        int area,
        int DBnum,
        int start,
        int len,
        byte[] buffer) {
        int errorState = 0;
        semaphore.enter();
        PDU p1 = new PDU(msgOut, PDUstartOut);

        p1.prepareWriteRequest();
        p1.addBitVarToWriteRequest(area, DBnum, start, len, buffer);

        errorState = exchange(p1);

        if (errorState == 0) {
            PDU p2 = new PDU(msgIn, PDUstartIn);
            p2.setupReceivedPDU();

            if (p2.mem[p2.param + 0] == PDU.FUNC_WRITE) {
                if (p2.mem[p2.data + 0] == (byte) 0xFF) {
                    if ((Nodave.Debug & Nodave.DEBUG_CONN) != 0)
                        System.out.println("writeBytes: success");
                    semaphore.leave();
                    return 0;
                }
            } else {
                errorState |= 4096;
            }
        }
        semaphore.leave();
        return errorState;
    }
```

Comment: ... or you can just use the JNI http://home.pacifier.com/~mmead/jni/cs510ajp/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Since the variable is ignored I would delete it.

However if it were not ignored you could sue

```
int[] a = { 1 };
writeBits(area, DBnum, 8*byteAdr+bitAdr, 1, a )  ;
// do something with a[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have pointers.
It has references:

c++:

```
Object *a=new Object();
```

java:

```
Object a=new Object();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how `daveWriteBits` uses `buffer`. If it is just treated as a simple integer, and if `daveSetBit` does not use the value of `a` after this call, just make it an `int`. No pointers/references.

If `daveSetBit` needs the value of `a` (after any potential modifications in `daveWriteBits`, then making a an [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) may help.

If there is some really fancy pointer stuff going on (treating `&a` itself as an address etc) then you may have to do a bit more design.

Answer (score 0):

Are you more familar with C++ or Java? The C++ code is treating an integer as an array of bytes. You can't do that directly in Java (I think) but you can do this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
new DataOutputStream(buf).write(a);
return writeBits(area, DBnum, 8*byteAdr+bitAdr, 1, buf );
```

Converts an integer to an array of bytes which you can then pass to writeBits. Untested code.

Comment: probably better to manually split the integer than to use `DataOutputStream`... that or use `ByteBuffer` the whole time.

Comment: @veer: Sure, the important point is that the equivalent in Java is a conversion to `byte[]`

Comment: @Elfoc `new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 }` assuming it expects it big-endian like Java is